# How does iteration of any enumerate object work in python?

Tags: python, enumerate

I have a list in python ([1,2,3]). I enumerate it using enumerate(l), where l is a list object. I can iterate the enumerate object only once -

```
for item in e:
    print i
```

This loop prints the enumerate object elements. But when I again loop through it, it prints nothing. What is happening in the background? Why does enumerate object does not print its elements on second iteration?

Comment: Are you doing `e = enumerate([1, 2, 3])` ?

Comment: Oops, sorry for the wrong duplicate. I intended to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2713712/2301450) question